# JavaScript/jQuery - Validating based on length

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm working on a simple form that I need to validate against UK postcodes.  No problem there but I need to validate depending on the character length.  The user can input only the first half of a postcode (i.e. SW1) or a full postcode (i.e. SW1 1AB).

I thought the best approach would be to check the length on KeyPress and validate against RegEx for either half a postcode or the whole thing.  See below:

```
jQuery('.ValPostCode').keyup(
    function(){

        if (jQuery(this).length < 5){
            jQuery.validator.addMethod("ValPostCode", function(value, element) {
                return this.optional(element) || /([A-PR-UWYZa-pr-uwyz]([0-9]{1,2}|([A-HK-Ya-hk-y][0-9]|[A-HK-Ya-hk-y][0-9]([0-9]|[ABEHMNPRV-Yabehmnprv-y]))|[0-9][A-HJKS-UWa-hjks-uw]))/.test(value);
            }, "Please enter a valid postcode");                            
        } else if (jQuery('.ValPostCode').length > 4) {
             jQuery.validator.addMethod("ValPostCode", function(value, element) {
            return this.optional(element) || /^(GIR\\s{0,1}0AA|[A-PR-UWYZ]([0-9]{1,2}|([A-HK-Y][0-9]|[A-HK-Y][0-9]([0-9]|[ABEHMNPRV-Y]))|[0-9][A-HJKS-UW])\\s{0,1}[0-9][ABD-HJLNP-UW-Z]{2})$/.test(value);
            }, "Please enter a valid postcode");
        }

    });
```

So, if the char length of `.ValPostCode` is less than 5 it validates only for the first half of a UK postcode, else it checks for a full and valid UK postcode.

At one point I was outputting the length of `.ValPostCode` but it always stopped at 1 (first keypress) and then didn't carry on any further (i.e. wouldn't count up with subsequent keypresses).

I hope I've explained myself clearly enough, please let me know if I'm not being clear.

I've searched for similar problems to try and fix this for myself but I couldn't find anything.  Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The length of `$(selector).length` (or `jQuery(selector).length`) will always be the number of elements on the screen that match the given selector. Try using `$(selector).val().length` to get the value of a form element and check its lenght instead.

Answer (score 1):

It seems as though you are setting up validator rules on every keypress unnecessarily

When the page first loads, you should only need to call something like this:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("ValPostCode", function(value, element) {
    if(value.length < 5) {
        return (insert partial postcode check here);
    } else {
        return  (insert whole postcode check here);
    }
}, "Please enter a valid postcode");
```

And should only call it once. JQuery will pick up the error on submit/change depending on how it is configured.

So there is no need for a keyUp event.

The main problem you were having (as someone else has already pointed out) is that you were returning the length of the jQuery object rather than the length of its value attribute.

Comment: Thanks for this, I'll re-work my code to remove the keypress.